# When I make a contract that inherits a contract, do I need to insert using phrase one more time?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

```
contract A {
   using SafeMath for uint256
}

contract B is A {
   //using SafeMath for uint256

   function mul () public {
     uint256 test = 1;
     test.mul(3);
   }
}
```

Without contract B's using phrase i encountered "Member "mul" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract uint256."

When i make contract that inherit other contract which has "using SafeMath for uint256", do i have to insert using phrase one more time?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the compiler version.

---

Since 0.7, you need to reimport the library in each contract separately.

From the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/contracts.html#using-for):

> The `using A for B;` directive is active only within the current scope (either the contract or the current module/source unit), including within all of its functions, and has no effect outside of the contract or module in which it is used.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.4.2/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract A {
   using SafeMath for uint256;
}

contract B is A {
    using SafeMath for uint256; // reimported the library

   function foo() pure public returns (uint256) {
     uint256 test = 1;
     return test.mul(3);
   }
}
```

---

However, in 0.6 and older versions, the imported library is available in the child contracts as well.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.4.2/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract A {
   using SafeMath for uint256;
}

contract B is A {
   // no need to reimport the library

   function foo() pure public returns (uint256) {
     uint256 test = 1;
     return test.mul(3);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! My curiosity has been solved.